# building a table-like structure from data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to build dynamically a table-like structure from a data-set on websites (in javascript)?

In pseudo-code something like:

```
 function pseudo(dataset) {
    <table>
    <th>dataset.name, dataset.id</th>
    foreach dataset.schedular.array as a {
     <tr><td>a.start_time</td><td>a.end_time</td><td>a.client.name</td></tr>
    }
    </table>
 }
```

and executed like:

```
 <div>
 <script>pseudo(json[employee[0]]);</script>
 </div>
```

In php i used smarty-templates to "fill" data into similar masks, now i need something similar in javascript.
Are jquery widgets or plugins that what i m looking for? And where can i find helpful tutorials or books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jQuery and the following construct. `employees` is an JS array of objects. The HTML table is prepared like this:

```
<table id="clients">
<thead><tr><th>Start</th><th>End</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Then the following jQuery-loop using [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is used to append the lines:

```
$.each(employees, function(index, employee){
    $('#clients > tbody').append(listItem(index, employee)); 
});
```

where `listItem()` is a function that returns the table line. Of course, this could be done more elegantly:

```
function listItem(index, employee) {
    var item =  '<tr>';
    item += '<td>' + employee.start_time + '</td>';
    item += '<td>' + employee.end_time + '</td>';
    item += '<td>' + employee.name + '</td>';
    item += '</tr>';
    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

your html page:

```
<div id="dataToDisplay"></div>
```

your java script function:

```
function pseudo(dataset) {
var tableContents = "<table>";
tableContents = tableContents+ "<th>"+dataset.name, dataset.id+"</th>";

foreach dataset.schedular.array as a {
 tableContents  =tableContents + "<tr><td>"+a.start_time+"</td><td>"+a.end_time+"</td><td>"+a.client.name+"</td></tr>";
}
tableContents = tableContents + "</table>";
document.getElementById("dataToDisplay").innerHTML = tableContents;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at "jqGrid"

> http://www.trirand.com/blog/

it's a plugin which takes JSON and biulds tables from it. However it uses jQuery.

Comment: +1 makes me happy too, anyway I'm glad I could be of help.. cheers!